# Problema sintaxe MySql gerando pelo PhpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Estou com um problema na hora que o MyAdmin gera um script de criação da tabela.

**O Script:**

```
CREATE TABLE `crud_ABC`.`cliente_ABC` ( `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `nome` VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL , `valor` DOUBLE(20) NOT NULL , `descricao` TINYTEXT NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`id`(10))) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

**Porém ele me reporta o erro de:**

> 1064 - Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a ') NOT NULL , `descricao` TINYTEXT NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`id`(10))) ENGINE = My' na linha 1

O que será que pode ser? Já tentei troca as aspas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há alguns problemas no seu código:

1. Você está passando apenas um valor para `double`. Nesse tipo você precisa informar o tamanho e o número de casas decimais. `DOUBLE(20,10) NOT NULL`
2. Você está passando o tamanho da chave primaria, isso não é necessário, na verdade é errado, basta apenas informar o campo. `PRIMARY KEY (id)`

**Segue exemplo:**

```
CREATE `crud_ABC`.`cliente_ABC` ( 
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nome` VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
    `valor` DOUBLE(20,10) NOT NULL,
    `descricao` TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

<sup>Referência: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html</sup>

Comment: Obg, me ajudou!! Eu tinha corrigido, mas o MyAdmin estava gerando o código assim. \o/